# How to "properly" (idiomatic) avoid CS9107 when passing primary constructor parameters to base

Tags: c#, .net, c#-12.0

With C# 12, we get primary constructors for normal classes.

Consider the following code:

```
new Derived("XXX").Test();

public class Base(string name)
{
    protected void Log() => Console.WriteLine("Base: " + name);
}

public class Derived(string name) : Base(name)
{
    public void Test()
    {
        base.Log();
        Console.WriteLine("Derived: " + name);
    }
}
```

This gives the following warning for the `string name` parameter to the `Derived` primary constructor:

> Program.cs(8,42): Warning CS9107 : Parameter 'string name' is captured into the state of the enclosing type and its value is also passed to the base constructor. The value might be captured by the base class as well.

How can I avoid this warning, should I just squelch it using a pragma? Or is there a better way to avoid it? Is the code written the wrong way? I am not sure I can see an alternative, other than to ditch the primary constructors and rewrite the whole thing to:

```
new Derived("XXX").Test();

public class Base
{
    protected readonly string _name;

    protected Base(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    protected void Log() => Console.WriteLine("Base: " + _name);
}


public class Derived : Base
{
    public Derived(string name) : base(name) { }

    public void Test()
    {
        base.Log();
        Console.WriteLine("Derived: " + base._name);
    }
}
```

Please advise.

---

**Note:** This is a contrived example, shortened down from a more complex class hiearchy using the configuration objects from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, where multiple levels of classes all need access to the configuration.

Comment: What happens if you use `this.name` instead of just `name` ?

Comment: It is an educational warning.  Like "we got this new feature but it has a problem you should be aware of".  Now you know, just turn it off.

Comment: @HansPassant what if Base changes name. (They are not readonly) then Derived would not see that.

Answer (score 7):

Using a property perhaps? You probably want to keep your fields private anyway.

```
public class Base(string name)
{
    protected string Name => name;
    protected void Log() => Console.WriteLine("Base: " + Name);
}

public class Derived(string name) : Base(name)
{
    public void Test()
    {
        base.Log(); 
        Console.WriteLine("Derived: " + Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> Is the code written the wrong way?

Yes, it's wrong.

`string name` in the primary constructor is just a **parameter**, but when you use it in the enclosing type, the compiler automatically turns it into a private field, so you created an additonal private field in the `Derived` class, and actually `name` in the statement `Console.WriteLine("Derived: " + name);` doesn't refer to the field in the base class. (In other word, if you have a method that changes `name` in the `Base` class, `Derived.Test` won't be changed)

To avoid the compiler automatically generating an unexpected field, you need to assign the parameter to a field or property as usual and not use this parameter in derived classes.

Comment: _”To correct this, you need to assign the parameter to a field or property as usual and not use the parameter to avoid the compiler automatically generating a field”_ - I feel like having to do this defeats the point of how primary ctors are meant to result in more succinct code - alas - 1 step forward, 2 steps back.

Comment: After what you commented, I realized that this statement was not quite right. I mean to correct this particular issue (referencing the wrong object). Actually, all you need to do is not use the parameters in the primary constructor in subclasses. Rephrased it.

Comment: @Dai I guess that is my real question here, it seems that in order to get rid of warnings introduced in class hierarchies, when using primary constructors, is to either not use primary constructors, or add extra code that I sort of felt the purpose of primary constructors was to get rid of. I will introduce a protected field in the base class and use that instead.

Comment: Not using the parameter in the derived class makes the warning disappear. To be more specific, you can actually use the parameter in a private readonly field, but not in a method.

Answer (score 0):

A little off topic but on the same problem. I think it is a case the IDE (Rider) has a bug, it shouldn't allow you to remove the private field as it causes the warning in question.

```
public class ComponentService(
    IRepository<Component, ComponentModel> repository,
    IContext context,
    IFilterService filterService)
    : ReadOnlyComponentService(repository, context), IComponentService
{
    // The compiler is informing me this can be removed
    private readonly IContext _context = context;
```

Comment: Arguably it is right - checkout this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77612002/2501279