# Unexplainable error: Record member must be a readable instance property or field of type 'T[]' to match positional parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to wrap several arrays of `Dto`'s in a wrapper, like this:

```cs
public sealed record SomeWrapper<T>(T[]? L1, T[]? L2, T[]? L3) 
    : SomeWrapper(L1, L2, L3) where T : Dto;

public record SomeWrapper(
    Dto[]? L1,
    Dto[]? L2,
    Dto[]? L3
);
```

because I wish to be able to initialize an array of `SomeWrapper`'s where T can be different, IE:

```cs
List<SomeWrapper> someWrappers = new List<SomeWrapper>()

someWrappers.Add(new SomeWrapper<SomeDto>());
someWrappers.Add(new SomeWrapper<SomeOtherDto>());
return someWrappers;
```

However, I'm getting the following error:
`Record member 'L1' must be a readable instance property or field of type 'T[]' to match positional parameter 'L1'`

I believe this code should work so I'm not sure what's going wrong here. This is what `Dto` looks like:

```cs
public interface Dto<T> : Dto where T : Entity.Entity;

public interface Dto
{
    string Id { get; init; }
};
```

`Entity` is just an empty interface for now.

I cannot explain this error and don't know how else to ask this questions (taking suggestions)

Comment: I think what are trying to reach is not allowed in records, please see this [git discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/discussions/46814)

Comment: Interesting. I can't honestly say I fully understand the discussion, but understand the consequences. Would a valid solution be to change the Dto's to a class? Trying this results in similair issues with casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me simplify your question, when you have:

```
public record SomeWrapper(Dto[]? L1);
```

The compiler automatically generates a public property for the same name:

```
public record SomeWrapper
{
    public Dto[]? L1 { get; init; }
    // ...other members
}
```

Now in the derived record, you declare a property with the same name:

```
public sealed record SomeWrapper<T>(T[]? L1) : SomeWrapper(L1) where T : class, Dto
```

The compiler will assume that `L1` is the property defined by the base class. However, since you declared a different type, it no longer works. This error message is somewhat misleading, as it suggests that you modify the type of the `L1` property of the base class.

Anyway, you need to resolve this conflict, and I think you don't want to encounter [an unexpected mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77302452/how-to-properly-idiomatic-avoid-cs9107-when-passing-primary-constructor-para/77303090#77303090). You need to manually declare a new property:

```
public sealed record SomeWrapper<T>(T[]? L1) : SomeWrapper(L1) where T : class, Dto
{
    public new T[]? L1 => (T[]?)base.L1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. When I apply your suggested solution, I get a new error: 
`Cannot convert type Dto[]? to T[]?`  Any suggestions?

Comment: I made some edits to more accurately reflect the issue and then the error occurs:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/t0tK28

Comment: Oh, I removed `T:class` constraint to simplify the problem, but your original code should keep it.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you mean that your solution does not work in my case?

Comment: Yes it works, I updated my answer, `where T : Dto` ---> `where T : class, Dto`.

Comment: This works! Could you please explain why the T : class is required? Also, all of my Dto instances are also records. Would I need to change them to classes and why?

Comment: Because C# requires that element types must be reference types in order to convert between arrays ([see 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#1035-explicit-reference-conversions)). Your Dto is an interface, withou this `T:class` constraint, the condition cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: I am now having serialization and deserialization issues. When serializing with L1 having one Dto, I get: `{"L1": [{}], "L2": [], "L3": []}`, so the Dto is not correctly serialized.

Comment: You can search for polymorphic deserailization, or ask a new question.